# Change folder location of .org.eclipse.sequoyah

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm an android developer and have just bought a new computer. On this i set out to move my userfolder to another drive and so far everything worked out ok.

But now I have this problem that when I start Motodev, or eclipse, and opens an not empty workspace, something, my guess sequoyah, creates a folder named: ".org.eclipse.sequoyah".

I can't find any place where I can change this.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can't change the folder.

The problem is that sequoyah is using `org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.getUserLocation()` which isn't returning the enviroment variable `%USERPROFILE%`, it's a bug in JVM which hasn't been fixed for about 6 years.